# Xamarin Android Facebook GameRequestDialog not calling callbacks

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using the Xamarin.Facebook.Android package for this. The dialog displays correctly and the requests go through to the correct recipients but the callbacks never get called. I'm not 100% sure where I'm supposed to get the CallbackManager from.

```
public class FacebookService : IFacebookService
{
    public void InviteFriends(FacebookInviteCallbacks facebookInviteCallbacks)
    {
        if (AppInviteDialog.CanShow())
        {
            var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity;
            var content = new GameRequestContent.Builder().
                SetTitle("Check out this game").
                SetMessage("Check out this game I play!").
                Build() as GameRequestContent;

            var dialog = new GameRequestDialog(activity);

            dialog.RegisterCallback(CallbackManagerFactory.Create(), new MyFacebookCallback(facebookInviteCallbacks));
            dialog.Show(content);                

        }
    }       
}

public class MyFacebookCallback : Java.Lang.Object, IFacebookCallback
{
    private FacebookInviteCallbacks facebookInviteCallbacks;

    public ImcFacebookCallback(FacebookInviteCallbacks facebookInviteCallbacks)
    {
        this.facebookInviteCallbacks = facebookInviteCallbacks;
    }

    public void OnCancel()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled sending invite");
    }

    public void OnError(FacebookException error)
    {
        facebookInviteCallbacks.FailedCallback(error.Message);
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

**Update**

From what I can tell from other examples I've seen, CallbackManagerFactory.Create() is correct.

Comment: Did you register an app for your application and go through the steps of [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)?

Comment: Yes. The dialog displays correctly and the requests get sent. The only issue I have is the callbacks don't get called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of digging and trial and error I finally got this working.

In my FacebookService class I added:

```
public static ICallbackManager callbackManager;
```

In the Invitefriends method, in the if statement I changed this:

```
dialog.RegisterCallback(CallbackManagerFactory.Create(), new MyFacebookCallback(facebookInviteCallbacks));
```

to

```
callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();
dialog.RegisterCallback(callbackManager, new ImcFacebookCallback(facebookInviteCallbacks));
```

In the MainActivity I added the following override.

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);                        

        Services.FacebookService.callbackManager.OnActivityResult(requestCode, (int)resultCode, data);
    }
```

That's all it took. I wish the package would have been better documented.